# How to run a graphical program from a restricted user

Tags: python, bash, permissions, sudo

I have two users. `admin` can see everything. `pi` is restricted.

I have a tkinter python application. `pi` must be able to run the program, but it cannot read any of the files directly. There is a `data.json` file that the application needs, but I don't want the user cheating by peaking at the file directly.

I added the following line to visudo:
`pi ALL=(admin) NOPASSWD: /home/admin/myapp/main.py` If I understand correctly, this will allow `pi` to switch to `admin` just when trying to run the python app.

Then I made a script `runapp.sh` with the line: `gksudo -u admin python3 /home/admin/myapp/main.py

I run the script as `pi` and nothing happens. Even when I run it from the terminal, there are no errors, but the app does not appear. Before, I tried using just sudo instead of gksudo and got the error `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"`, so I know it is at least trying to execute the python code.

What do I need to change to get this working?

Comment: Linux scripts (including Python) have limited privilege escalation. What you want is not possible. This is not a Pi specific question.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `gksudo` is deprecated, and not needed in your case. You should use `sudo` instead. The failure you're seeing has nothing to do with `sudo`, you're likely running your script before a GUI environment has started, so there is no display to connect to.

Second, you try to run `/home/admin/myapp/main.py` as the `pi` user. Normally, `pi` won't even have read access inside `/home/admin`. You should place executable scripts somewhere else, e.g. in `/usr/local/bin`.

Finally, you authorize the `pi` user to run `/home/admin/myapp/main.py`, but you actually run `python3` instead, so your `sudo` rule won't even apply. Your `runapp.sh` should contain the line

```
sudo -u admin /home/admin/myapp/main.py
```

and your `main.py` should start with `#!/usr/bin/env python3` if `python3` is not the default Python interpreter.

Comment: More on `gksudo` being deprecated: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/133072/33476